# How to display .eps file in the SharePoint picture library?

Tags: 2013, picture-library, image-display

I have a picture library in which I will have .eps files as a record document.

After uploading the .eps file I am seeing the blank document thumbnail. But, however I want to see the document. Is there any way to see it? I searched over internet but could not find better solution. Are there any third party tool available to view the .eps file?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box SharePoint support for previewing those files in an library view. You'll have to go custom code or third-party if you want to be able to see these images in-browser. Just Google 'sharepoint eps preview' and you can find several results.

On a minor note, you can change the icon for file formats away from the blank one using [these](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/832809) instructions from MS. For 2013, just use /15 instead of /14.